# Custom Build Step Configuration is not persistent. It disappears on Reload or server restart

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I created a custom build step. Added a text area in config.jelly. Whatever I am putting in the text area is getting saved but on restarting the server or reloading it disappears. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just fix this by overriding the configure() method in the Descriptor.
Code looks like...

```
@Extension
public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder>{
private String text;
public DescriptorImpl(){
        load();
}
    @Override
    public boolean configure(StaplerRequest req, JSONObject json) throws hudson.model.Descriptor.FormException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text = json.getString("text");
        req.bindJSON(this, json);
        save();
        return super.configure(req, json);
        //return true;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```